# How to login oracle 11g on browser?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I'm new in oracle. But I'm using 11g standard edition now via SQL Developer. When I use 'SYS as SYSDBA' user along with the password then it'll works fine. But when I use 'HR or SCOTT as NORMAL' user along with the password then that error showing. I've attached that picture here. I also attached 'sys' user after login picture. Please help me. How to fix this problem.

Here is the Images Below----

[image: 1. Error page with User SCOTT]

[image: 2. SYS user after login]

Answer (score 0):

are you unlocked the user?
you can use the below query to unlock a user. run it in SQL*Plus by sysdba user.

`ALTER USER SCOTT ACCOUNT UNLOCK;`

Comment: It's  already unlocked while I'm installing it. from cmd prompt that user pass is working but when I'm going through browser then that error comes.